# Show only 1 image from each group instead of showing all of them from each group

Tags: c#, asp.net

Structure of my WebPage looks something like:

```
<asp:Repeter>
    <asp:Repeter>
        <asp:Repeter>
            <asp:DataList>
                <asp:Image />
            </asp:DataList>
        </asp:Repeter>
    </asp:Repeter>
</asp:Repeter>
```

In the output of my Webform, I get all the images in the DataList control. But I want to display just 1st Image from each group.

Here is my code:

**.aspx:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgMinimizeCategory" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Minimize.jpg" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCategory" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName")%>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Children") %>'>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Image ID="imgMinimizeGroup" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Minimize.jpg" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblGroup" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductName")%>' />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:Repeater ID="ChildrenRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("Children") %>'>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:DataList ID="dlProductImages" runat="server" DataSource='<%#Eval("Images") %>' DataKeyField="ImageId"
                                                    RepeatColumns="6">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                                        <asp:Image ID="imageProductImage" runat="server" Height="180px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImageUrl") %>' Width="180px" />
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </asp:DataList>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:Repeater>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        MenuItem SelectedMenuItemInMaster = Session["SelectedMenuItem"] as MenuItem;

        ParentRepeater.DataSource = GetProducts(SelectedMenuItemInMaster.Value);
        ParentRepeater.DataBind();
    }
}

private List<Product> GetProducts(string selectedValue)
{
    List<Product> ProductsOfSelectedMenuItem = new List<Product>();

    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("spGetMenuData", con);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (dr["ParentID"].ToString().Trim() == selectedValue)
        {
            Product item = new Product();
            item.ProductName = dr["ProductName"].ToString();
            item.ProductId = (int)dr["ProductId"];
            item.ParentId = (int)dr["ParentId"];

            foreach (DataRow drChild in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                if (drChild["ParentID"].ToString() == dr["ProductId"].ToString())
                {
                    GetChildItems(ds, drChild, item);
                }
            }

            ProductsOfSelectedMenuItem.Add(item);
        }
    }

    SqlDataAdapter daImages = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Images", con);
    DataSet dsImages = new DataSet();
    daImages.Fill(dsImages);

    foreach (Product p in ProductsOfSelectedMenuItem)
    {
        if (p.Children != null)
        {
            foreach (Product child in p.Children)
            {
                foreach (Product c in child.Children)
                {
                    foreach (DataRow drImages in dsImages.Tables[0].Rows)
                    {
                        if (c.ProductId == (int)drImages["ProductId"])
                        {
                            if (c.Images == null)
                            {
                                c.Images = new List<Image>();
                            }

                            c.Images.Add(new Image() { ImageId = (int)drImages["ImageId"], ImageUrl = drImages["ImageUrl"].ToString(), ProductId = (int)drImages["ProductId"] });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return ProductsOfSelectedMenuItem;
}

private static void GetChildItems(DataSet ds, DataRow dr, Product item)
{
    Product childItem = new Product();
    childItem.ProductName = dr["ProductName"].ToString();
    childItem.ProductId = (int)dr["ProductId"];
    childItem.ParentId = (int)dr["ParentId"];

    foreach (DataRow drChild in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        if (drChild["ParentID"].ToString() == dr["ProductId"].ToString())
        {
            GetChildItems(ds, drChild, childItem);
        }
    }

    if (item.Children == null)
    {
        item.Children = new List<Product>();
    }

    item.Children.Add(childItem);
}
```

I know, you are thinking that this is a very silly question as I am adding all the images to the collection. But let me explain you. I will use all the images in my next programming step. So, I don't want a collection that does not get images. In short, I want all the images in the collection. When I declare `DataSource='<%# Eval("Images")%>'` in `DataList` Tag, I would like to query the collection here. But I don't know how.....

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: You can implement a method in code behind that you refer to in the `DataSource` attribute like `DataSource='<%# MyFilteredImageCollection(Eval("Images")) %>'` and have the method return a subset of the images based on what you need.

Comment: @scheien Thanks. I gave it a try and it works exactly as I want. Can you please post it as answer, so that I can accept it. Also, I would like to ask you 1 question. While using repeater control, I saw that, At every iteration, it starts with a new line. Can I control that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a method in code behind that you refer to in the DataSource attribute, and have the method return a subset of the images based on your needs.

`DataSource='<%# MyFilteredImageCollection(Eval("Images")) %>'`

Comment: Can you please answer my another question in above comment?

Comment: I would need to see some rendered html for that question. It may be better suited as a new question though.

Comment: Just a minute I will update my question with the image of output.

Comment: If you want the images side by side, you may have to set the css property `display: inline-block`

Comment: That does not work. After taking a look at rendered html I found that ItemsTemplate is converted to `table`.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I got the solutiojn. I just replaced the DataList with a Repeater control and it now works as expected.